# Load another page(data-target) by using ajax in mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

Load another page using ajax without refreshing the page ,load first an image(loading gif) then the view.

```
<a id="id1" class="list-group-item"  data-target="@Url.Action("LiveMatches", "home")">
    <span class="badge" style="font-size:10px;color:#fff" id="LiveMatchesNumber">0</span>
    <span style="font-size:10px;font-weight: 900;">@index.Index.livematches</span>
</a>
```

```
   $(function () {
   $(".list-group-item").on("click", function () {
   var thebutton = $(this);
   var url = thebutton.attr("data-target");
   var target1 = $("#mainInfo");
   target1.empty().addClass("backgrounLoadinImage").addClass("backgrounLoadinImageSmall");
   $.ajax({
   type: "post",
   url: url,
   success: function (data, text) {
   target1.empty().html(data);
   target1.removeClass("backgrounLoadinImage").removeClass("backgrounLoadinImageSmall");
   },
   error: function (request, status, error) {
          alert(request + error);
         target1.removeClass("backgrounLoadinImage").removeClass("backgrounLoadinImageSmall");
          }
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `event` parameter of the `click` event in your callback function signature and then call the `event.preventDefault();` to stop the redirection.

```js
$(".list-group-item").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('not redirected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="https://google.com" class="list-group-item">click me</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did and it worked,but my problem is that i have a list with links and i want to open multiple links by using the same script

```
 $(function(){
       // don't cache ajax or content won't be fresh
       $.ajaxSetup ({
           cache: false
       });
       var ajax_load = "<img src='http://automobiles.honda.com/images/current-offers/small-loading.gif' alt='loading...' />";

       // load() functions
       var loadUrl = '@Url.Action("Index","Home")';
       $("#id1").click(function(){
           $("#mainInfo").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
       });
   });
```